# How to write wild card in less

Tags: html, css, less

I want a way to represent the following in less.

`row-fluid [class*="span"]`

This means it should select all elements which have class row fluid and then select all elements which will have class which has word span in it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Write as-is provided in question. It should work. (Do note that a space between `.row-fluid` and `[class*="span"]` would mean it would select child elements of `.row-fluid` which has `span` in their class name).

Comment: Do you mean this way : 
.row-fluid{
[class*="span"]{
//
}
}

Comment: Why do you need nesting? You can write it exactly as provided in question. Just `.row-fluid [class*="span"]` or `.row-fluid[class*="span"]` as you need.

Comment: I want to use less syntax. Anyways I have got the solution. Thanks :)

Comment: It's nice to know that you've got the solution but one suggestion that I'd give you is to not use nesting (Less features) just for the sake of using it. Use it if it gives you a real advantage or otherwise stick with CSS syntax itself :)

Comment: Valid css is also valid less. So you don't _have_ to use the less syntax. Especially if, like in this case, less is more!

Comment: Thanks guys. Shall keep that in mind